# IDEA, Android UI Render error, null pointer

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a problem with creating custom view. Here is code:

```
package com.example.App;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;

    public class v extends View {

        public v(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public v(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public v(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use it in layout and getting render error(`NullPointerException`), here is what IDEA has jenerate in layout code:

```
 <view android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           class="com.example.App.v" android:id="@+id/view" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: Post your stack trace, are you sure that this class is throwing the NPE? It doesn't do *anything* besides call up to the superclass. Or is IDEA itself throwing the NPE?